# how to remove a particular occurances from sequence clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

If I have sequence

```
[1 1 1 1 3 2 4 1]
```

how can I remove a particular number from that sequence? For example

**(remove [1 1 1 1 3 2 4 1] 1) -> [3 2 4]**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a set as a predicate to remove, because sets can be called as functions.

```
(remove #{1} [1 1 1 1 3 2 4 1])
=> (3 2 4)
```

wrap that in `(vec ..)` if you need the result to be a vector.

The bonus of that approach is that you could remove many arbitrary values by sticking them in the set. If it's just one, this of course works too:

```
(remove #(= 1 %) [1 1 1 1 3 2 4 1])
```